# jQuery hotkeys working for any key, not only for the designated

Tags: jquery, key, hotkeys

I added this code to my site:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'i', function(){
$("#af").click();
return false;});
```

The problem is that it works with any key, not only for the 'i'. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `'i'` is a parameter which is passed to your callback function. It has no effect on what character codes your event will respond to. You can do that via

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e){
   if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == 'I') {
      $("#af").click();
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: now it works, i wrote that because i was using jquery.hotkeys plugin https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Comment: I've never used that plugin, but given that it's written by the creator of jQuery, I'm guessing it's not a bug in the plugin. If you give a complete example of the code on http://jsfiddle.net, then people will be able to help. It's likely that the plugin isn't loaded when you're binding the event. If you're interested in help with that, it should be posted as a new question.

Comment: Last I checked, the docs on the jQuery HotKeys Github project page don't match the actual behavior. Instead of `.bind('keydown', 'i', function)`, the plugin overloads the event namespace to supply the keys. For your example, you'd do `bind('keydown.i', function)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because [jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) said :

> event.which normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is
>   recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input. For more
>   detail, read about [event.charCode on the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode#Notes).

then better to use

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 73) {   
        $("#af").click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode =='i') {   
        $("#af").click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: `keyCode` will be a numeric value (e.g. **i = 73**), you'll need to look up the key-value pairs; or use `String.fromCharCode(code)`